# get sd card path in android vs hard coded path

Tags: android

my code works fine, it downloads image to sd card, however , i get this warning where i defined my sd card path **"Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead"**

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/.temp");//.temp is the image file name
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
    }
```

the problem is, if i use the suggested solution, then i won't be able to give my downloaded file a new name (".temp")

Comment: OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".temp").getAbsolutePath())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with files and directories, it's better to work with `File` objects rather than with strings. Here's how you can address the warning:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File tmpFile = new File(dir, ".temp");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
```

That creates a `File` object that points to a file named `".temp"` in the environment's external storage directory. It then opens it for writing using a different constructor of the `FileOutputStream` class.

If you need the file path as a string instead (say, for printing), you can do that too:

```
String tmpFileString = tmpFile.getPath();
```

Or if you decide to use the `java.nio` API in the future and need a `Path` object:

```
Path tmpFilePath = tmpFile.toPath();
```

Comment: what is the difference between string and path?

Comment: @abbie - A `String` is just that -- a piece of text. A `Path` object is part of the `java.nio` API. For your purposes, a `File` would probably be the best thing to use; you can create a `FileOutputStream` passing a `File` as an argument and it works perfectly well.

Comment: should i replace " OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/.temp");" **with** " String tmpFile = new File(dir, ".temp").getPath();"

Comment: @abbie - No. See my edit. You should replace it with `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);`, where `tmpFile` is the `File` object.