# Android - get SD card path location after getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-intent, storage, android-sdcard

So there are many questions about getting the path of the SD card (external storage) here on SO. The problem is the function 99% of SO answer post has been [deprecated in API 29](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) i.e. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) suggests the following as alternatives

> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage
> devices is deprecated. When an app targets [Build.VERSION_CODES.Q](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#Q), the
> path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to
> apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external
> storage by migrating to alternatives such as
> [Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore), or
> [Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

Using **Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)** with **Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**

Using `Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)` suggestion found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)). The [File.getAbsolutePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#getAbsolutePath()) in the example below for `file` returns a path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/${getPackageName()}/files
```

**Code Example**

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "VideoFile.mp4");

try {
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.video_file);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(data);
    os.write(data);
    is.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
}
```

This copies files to external private storage, however attempting to open the file using an intent will result in an Android Exception:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

// type of file to view
in.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

// ask some other app to deal with it
startActivity(in);
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/${getPackageName()}/files/talking.mp4 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2141)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2391)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:11152)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:11104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1722)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
    at ${getPackageName()}.MainActivity.btnPlayIntentClicked(MainActivity.java:132)
```

**Question:**

What alternative does Android provide to get the path of the sdcard/external storage e.g. '/sdcard' (without hardcoding, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613425/get-sd-card-path-in-android-vs-hard-coded-path)) or getting `/storage/emulated/0/` without hardcoding?

Comment: The point is that the path of external storage is not especially useful, particularly starting next year when you need to raise your `targetSdkVersion` to `30`. You won't be able to write there (as you seem to be trying to do). "however attempting to open the file using an intent will result in an Android Exception:" -- `Uri.fromFile()` has been largely useless for four years. Use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method.

Comment: Just use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to give the root of external storage. It works. If that path is usefull is another story. But you can let Android 19 behave as it was before 10. So usefull. On 11 use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

Comment: @blackapps getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is also deprecated in 29. My question is based around the deprecation of these functions and what **alternatives** are available.

Comment: There are no alternatives. Use the old ones. Deprecated does not mean you cannot use them or that they do not work. Use them.